# Sql query correction one to many tables

Tags: mysql

I have two tables one is users and second is user_education.One users can have more than one education listing so i want to get the latest user education listing

```
users
===============
1-id
2-email

member_experience 
==============
1-id
2-user_id
3-designation
```

user id 1 has 4 enteries in user_education so i want to get the last record enter designation of the user

original full query is like this

```
SELECT u.id,u.name,u.gender,u.email,file_managed.file_name,file_managed.file_path 
from users as u 

INNER JOIN member_experience on (SELECT uid  FROM member_experience where member_experience.uid=u.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)=u.id 

LEFT JOIN file_managed on file_managed.id= u.fid 

where u.user_type ='individual' AND u.gender='male'


"INNER JOIN member_experience on (SELECT uid  FROM member_experience where member_experience.uid=u.id ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 1)=u.id "
```

this portion has problem as users has many record in member_experience table but i want to get only one which is latest.

thanks

Comment: The tables in your query are not the ones in your question; makes it hard to know what you want.  Member_experience might be what you are calling user_education, but if so, you aren't selecting any columns from it, so it's hard to see what it would mean to get the latest one

Comment: Sorry actually it is member_experience table i have edit the post

Comment: and what do you want to get from the one that is only the latest?  you aren't selecting anything from that table

Comment: Thanks for comments but i have found the solution already

Answer (score 0):

Devolve the acquisition of the last record to the where statement.

drop table if exists member_experience;
    create table member_experience(id int auto_increment primary key, userid int);

```
insert into member_experience (userid) values
(1),(2),(1);

select * from member_experience

SELECT u.id,m.id 
from users as u 
join member_experience m on m.userid = u.id
where m.id = (SELECT max(m.id)  FROM member_experience m where m.userid = u.id)
order by u.id
```

Or if you want to include those with no experience

```
SELECT u.id,m.id 
from users as u 
left join member_experience m on m.userid = u.id
where (m.id = (SELECT max(m.id)  FROM member_experience m where m.userid = u.id)
        or m.id is null)

        and u.id < 4
order by u.id
```

Comment: Thanks for quick reply query works but it only shows users which has the experience.I want to get all the users no matter it has experience or not but if they have more than one experience enteries then only latest one should show

Comment: Code added to include those with no experience.

Comment: Same result only two records with experience is showing in my db 9 records should be shown .In where clause if m.id = null then user record should show but it is not showing if a user does not have the experience record in member_experience table should this query  work

Comment: You did take out the and u.id < 4 ? If you can publish minimal sample data as text in the question I would be happy to revisit.